# What is the max of $x+y+z$ where $(x,y,z)$ is a real solution of the system

Tags: functions, systems-of-equations

> I am trying to calculate the maximum of $x +y +z$ and $(x_0 ,y_0,z_0)$ is a real solution of the system:
> $$2x=y+ \frac{2}{y}$$
> $$2y=z+ \frac{2}{z}$$
> $$2z=x+ \frac{2}{x}$$

I tried to sum them and got that

$$x+y+z=2\left( \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z} +\frac{1}{x} \right)$$

and with  $$(x+y+z)\left(\frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{z} +\frac{1}{x} \right) ≥9,$$
I got

$$x+y+z≥3\sqrt{2}.$$

I am stuck here because they want the maximum of the sum. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: i am very sorry Martin ,i put 1 instead of 2 in the system ,i edited now

Comment: Check this: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2146245p15795814, or this: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c4h1903093p13015710

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to notice that $(x,y,z)$ must have the same sign. In other to maximize $x+y+z$, we must have $$\color{red}{x,y,z >0}\tag{1}$$

We have also that
$$2x =y+\frac{1}{y} \ge2\sqrt{y\cdot \frac{2}{y}} = 2\sqrt{2}$$
So, we can deduce easily $$\color{red}{x,y,z \ge \sqrt{2}}\tag{2}$$

WOLG, suppose $x\le y$, then

- subtract the first and second equations:
  $$2(x-y) = (y-z)\left(1-\frac{2}{yz}  \right) \implies y\le z$$
- subtract the second and third equations :
  $$2(y-z) = (z-x)\left(1-\frac{2}{zx}  \right) \implies z\le x$$
  we deduce that $\color{red}{x\le y\le z\le x}$. So, $$\color{red}{x=y=z}\tag{3}$$

From $(1),(2)(3)$ we deduce that in order to reach the maximum, we must have
$$\color{red}{x=y=z=\sqrt{2}}$$
and the maximum is $\color{red}{x+y+z = 3\sqrt{2}}$.

**Remark**: there are only 2 real solutions $(x,y,z= = (\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$ or $(-\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2})$

Comment: The question was updated as a $2$ was missing from the numerators on the right hand side of the three constraints.

Comment: @smcc I just change my answer to the modified question. It must be ok now.